# Why does chrome.storage.local save only the last record?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension in which I need to save data in `chrome.storage.local`. But, it saves only last record data. Can you explain me what am I doing wrong?

Ordinary localStorage is bad, because after resetting settings in the Chrome browser, localStorage is empty.

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    if (request.type === 'setInLocalStorage') {
        var key = request.key;
        //alert(key);

        chrome.storage.local.set({key: request.data},function () {
            alert('data was saved');
        });

    }
    return true;
});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, SendResponse) {
    if (request.type === 'getFromStorage') {
        chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (items) {
            var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
            if (allKeys.length != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < allKeys.length; i++) {
                    alert(items[allKeys[i]]);
                    if (items[allKeys[i]] === request.value) {
                        SendResponse(true);
                    } else if (i === allKeys.length - 1) {
                        SendResponse(false);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                SendResponse(false);
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Why are you sending messages around to `get()` and `set()` `storage.local`? `storage.local` is available from both content scripts and scripts running in the background context.  There should be no need to message the information around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the most recently saved value exists in `storage.local`, because you repeatedly store all values into the property `'key'`, which is overwritten each time you call `chrome.storage.local.set()`.  Basically, you are not creating the Object you think you are for your call to `chrome.storage.local.set()`.

You use the [Object literal/Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) as:

```js
{key: request.data}
```

This is equivalent to:

```js
{'key': request.data}
```

It does not substitute in the value of the variable `key`. So, every time you attempt to save, you are storing the data in the property `'key'`, not the key which you are passing in the message (i.e. `request.key`).

You can use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) directly within the Object initializer which you are already using:

```
{[key]: request.data}
```

This results in the contents of the variable `key` being used as the property to which to assign the value of `request.data`.

Which would make your code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    if (request.type === 'setInLocalStorage') {
        var key = request.key;
        //alert(key);

        chrome.storage.local.set({[key]: request.data},function () { //only this line changes
            alert('data was saved');
        });
    }
    return true;
});
```

Alternately, you can do the same thing, but a bit more verbose, by first creating the object and then setting the property:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    if (request.type === 'setInLocalStorage') {
        var setObject = {};
        setObject[request.key] = request.data;
        //alert(key);

        chrome.storage.local.set(setObject,function () {
            alert('data was saved');
        });
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
var key = request.key;
//alert(key);

chrome.storage.local.set({key: request.data},function () {
    alert('data was saved');
});
```

When you create an object using the notation `{key: value}`, the key is always "key", and not the value of any variable named `key`.

You can do it in the following way:

```
var data={};
data[request.key]=request.data;
chrome.storage.local.set(data,function () {
    alert('data was saved');
});
```

Or, closer to your current code, using square brackets (in that position `[]` doesn't define an array, is the valid notation to define the key as the value of a given variable):

```
var key = request.key;
//alert(key);

chrome.storage.local.set({[key]: request.data},function () {
    alert('data was saved');
});
```